# Kruskal-Wallis Test shows significance, but Pairwise Wilcoxon Rank Sum Test does not

Tags: r, wilcoxon-signed-rank, kruskal-wallis-test

I used the following code to perform a Kruskal-Wallis test on a dataset, which gave me a significant p-value (5.159e-06).

However, when I then use pairwise.wilcox.test() to perform a Pairwise Wilcoxon Rank Sum Test, no p-value between groups shows significance. Same thing when I get the significance letters with multcompLetters2(), where every group gets the letter A.

I'm wondering if that may be affected by the low number of numeric values by group (<5).

**Dataset**

```
Table1 <- structure(list(Zone = c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "5", "5", "5", "6",                                                                                         "6", "6", "7", "7", "7", "8", "8", "8", "9", "9", "9",                                                      "10", "10", "10", "11", "11", "11", "12", "12", "12", "13", "13",                                                                                            "13", "14", "14", "14", "15", "15", "15", "16", "16", "16",                                                                                           "17", "17", "17"), Response = c(13.352, 
14.0146, 14.1781, 5.62932, 5.80346, 5.89391, 8.44548, 8.30884, 
8.26276, 6.60561, 6.33102, 6.61262, 7.77392, 8.3299, 8.54713, 
5.93946, 6.10588, 6.04483, 11.8243, 11.9579, 11.7664, 15.9763, 
15.4358, 15.6228, 21.1587, 21.2021, 21.2392, 4.09461, 4.10504, 
4.04033, 13.2888, 13.0089, 12.843, 13.463, 13.4929, 13.4582, 
4.1468, 4.13986, 3.77537, 3.99322, 3.80697, 4.0791, 14.874, 
14.8796, 15.0262, 15.126, 14.7747, 15.1524, 8.86868, 8.80423, 
8.76666)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -51L))
```

**Kruskal-Wallis Test**

```
kruskal.test(Response ~ Zone, data = Table1)
```

**Wilcoxon Test**

```
wilcox <- pairwise.wilcox.test(Table1$Response, Table1$Zone, p.adjust.method = "BH")
```

Comment: You have three observations for each Zone and are doing a non-parametric rank test so, no matter what the data is, before any adjustment the probability of seeing full separation in a pairwise comparison when there is no distinction in the distributions is about $\frac{2}{6 \choose 2}=0.1$ and so "not significant" in every case; you need more observations per Zone to get anything useful from your pairwise rank test.

Comment: The fact that $130$ of the $136$ pairwise tests had this full separation would have been highly improbable if there are no distinctions in the distributions overall, so it is no surprise that the overall Kruskal-Wallis test did have low $p$-value.

Comment: @Henry:  Can you add this as an answer, in the answer box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Requested from comments:*

You have three observations for each of the $17$ Zones and are doing a non-parametric rank test so, no matter what the data is, before any adjustment the probability of seeing full separation in a pairwise comparison when there is no distinction in the distributions is about $\frac{2}{6 \choose 2}=0.1$ and so "not significant" in every case; you need more observations per Zone to get anything useful from your pairwise rank test.

The fact that $130$ of the ${17 \choose 2}=136$ pairwise tests had this full separation would have been highly improbable if there were no distinctions in the distributions overall, so it is no surprise that the overall Kruskal-Wallis test did have a low $p$-value.